# Why Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function say3<T>(a: T): T { 
    return a + 1; 
} 
let speak = say3<number>(1)
```

I tried the demo, but it says " Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.'
T isn't a number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is with the operation `+ 1`. Typescript can't determine if you're doing a number sum, a string concatenation or even a `BigInt` operation. In fact, because the result of a variable of type T(where T is any possible type) plus 1 is not well defined and might even return a type different from T! A paticular case that comes to mind is `[]+1=="1"` or `{}+1==1`, cases where `T` is an `Array` and an `Object` while the function would return a `string` or a `number` respectively.

When you template your functions, the function needs to be well defined regardless of possible T types. In other words, yeah `T` isn't a number even if you explicitly pass a number later.

A possible fix would be to explicitly determine that the return type is a number and to limit T:

```
function say3<T extends number>(a: T): number {
  return a + 1;
}
let speak = say3<number>(1)
```

Or if you really want T to work with other types, you can do operator overloading:

```
function say3(a: string): string 
function say3(a: number): number
function say3(a: any[]): string
function say3(a: object): number
function say3(a: null): number
function say3(a: undefined): number
function say3(a: any) { 
    return a+1; 
} 
let speak = say3(1)
```

Either way, you can't call an operator over a non-defined type.

Comment: thank!before this,i think in ts,generics specified type in input <number>,but now i know it.