# TypeScript function one value or list of values

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create the following `double` function:

```
type MaybeArray<T> = T | T[];

function double<T extends MaybeArray<number>>(data: T): T extends number[] ? number[] : number {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    // TypeScript does not recognize that `data` here is an array of numbers.
    return data.map((n) => double(n));
  }

  // TypeScript does not recognize that `data` here is a number.
  return data * 2;
}
```

<sup>[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAggJzQgPAFQHxQC8UOUAPiQNoC6A3ALABQTAZgK4B2AxsAJYD2HKABN+bRABsIuKBAAewCB2EBnWAmTpMILBzYBbZGjx4AFMLjA4ALhIBKW6XmLlavYYhoaUAPxR3Rt62AZ5QAN5MUFC8LFCmWggAdLwqCSDmlnB2duGRUVAA9AUk4BAAylxovGDAIvwQbvy1aBBc-ADmHLwAXtDAABaWUAAGFlbDUP2e0ClQcEJwGAhQ-LEhaCqJeVEtwGxoQmNwifpwYKamHDmEBKLiUpfZDIxRAL5MeUUlkBVVNXUNfxNKAtNqdHp9Qa1UaZCZTFrRNRwfwGIxbF4giB7A4iTJQABUUAATM9XkA)</sup>

The function should return the double of the given number, or an array with the doubled numbers if a list is given. *Please see that errors in the playground that I linked above.*

But TypeScript does not recognize that inside the `if` block the `data` parameter is an array of numbers and outside the `if` block `data` is a plain number.

How can I fix that?

---

P.S.: I know that by using function overloads I would solve this problem, but I want to know if it is possible to fix it without any overloads.

Comment: It happens because of [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) TS design limitation: generics that extend union types cannot be properly narrowed via control flow analysis. Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347967/how-can-i-make-this-generic-typescript-function-work-as-expected).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the answer to your post can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53511376/2358409

As an alternative, you could try the following:

```
type T = number | number[];
function double(data: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        return data.map((n) => <number>double(n));
    }
    return data * 2;
}
```